# How to store multi place borders coordinates many times to create a polyline

Tags: arrays, laravel, save, coordinates

I'm having a big headache with how to store multiple borders for a place.
I got a place table which contains id-lat-long-totalspace-borders in this border I want to save multiple latlong.

Comment: What have you done so far? Currently how are you storing the borders?

Comment: i did not store them yet or I can say I could not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, on top of mind I have 2 options:

1. In your current `borders` field. Store the borders in a specific format, e.g. `"112.12,32.42;421.42,42,53;421.42,42,53;421.42,42,53;421.42,42,53"`. In this format, each border is separated by semicolon, the long and lat is separated by comma
2. Or create a separate table `borders` and store them in that table, the fields are `id`, `place_id`, `lat`, `long`